# Using sidecar container to retrieve Chef data bag secret value

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-registry

I have already created a databag item which is existing on the chef server.
Now, I am trying to use sidecar container to retrieve Chef data bag secret value.

I am creating the data bag as follows:

```
knife data bag create bag_secrets bag_masterkey --secret-file C:\path\data_bag_secret
```

What logic do i need to create to retrieve Chef data bag secret value within docker sidecar container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass Chef data bag secret to a docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338090/how-to-pass-chef-data-bag-secret-to-a-docker-container)